# Ho do I generate a value automatically in Firestore document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My documents require an integer value which is used as index for queries. Each document contains an index field ( number)  where I am assigning the values manually one by one. Maybe somewhere I can put something that stores the current index value and increments it and assigns it to the new document as it's index value whenever I create the new document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways to handle this, though I don't know that you want to use an integer based index for your document id. If you delete one, your index is now off. And what about write failures? Race conditions? Etc. You may want to rethink your data structure & organization.

#### If using an integer is not required as the document id:

```js
// Create a reference to a new document inside your collection
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('myCollectionName').doc()

// Now you have an auto-generated document id you can use for your code
const myData = {...}

const setDoc = await firebase.firestore().collection('myCollectionName').doc(ref.id).set(myData)
```

#### If using an integer *is* required:

You'll want a separate collection/object that keeps track of the latest index so you don't run into collisions. Then, you'll want to increment that value to get the next index, and then use that as your id. This comes with inherent problems like...what if the data is bad as you try to enter it, but after you've incremented the value...etc.

```js
// Collection: myIndex
// Doc: index
// Value: {lastIndex: 1}
const doc = await firebase.firestore().collection('myIndex').doc('index')

// You now have the last index value using:
const lastIndex = doc.val().lastIndex
const nextIndex = lastIndex + 1
const myData = {...}

// Now run a batched operation to write to both documents
const batch = firebase.firestore().batch()

// Update the index document
const indexUpdateRef = firebase.firestore().collection('myIndex').doc('index')
batch.update(indexUpdateRef, {lastIndex: nextIndex})

// Add your new myData document
const newDataRef = firebase.firestore().collection('myCollectionName').doc(nextIndex)
batch.set(newDataRef, myData)

// Commit the batch
await batch.commit()
```

As I said - I think this is a *really* bad idea and workflow, but it's doable. Lots missing from keeping this in sync as well.

#### In either case above...

You can take advantage of `FieldValue.increment()` to help auto increment your integer values, but that will add to more reads & writes, longer processing time, and higher charges for all of that. Which is why I started with and maintain that you should probably rethink your data structure or consider a RDB if you want autoincremented indices.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in Cloud Firestore.  You will need to come up with all the values yourself.  The only thing that Firestore can generate for you automatically is a timestamp based on the server's sense of time.